# How to select date range with POSIXct type

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm working on a project where I want to track birth totals nine months after another event (wondering if there is a correlation).  It was suggested I use the "lubridate" package to combine MONTH and YEAR in my data frames (which I was seeking to do).

I have successfully used lubridate in both data frames.  The problem is that I only want to select a certain date range from one of those data frames, and I'm having difficulty doing this.  I think it's because the type of data is POSIXct:

```
str(model.weather)
'data.frame':   467 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DATE      : POSIXct, format: "2006-01-01" "2006-01-01" "2006-01-01" "2006-01-01" ...
 $ EVENT_TYPE: Factor w/ 8 levels "Hail","Heavy Snow",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 ...
```

I have tried converting to numeric, but unfortunately that does horrible, horrible things to the data in my DATE variable.  I've tried converting to factor, character, and integer, too - none of them seem to work.

I'm trying to use the "subset" function to select the necessary date range:

```
model.weather <- subset(model.weather, DATE >= 2006-04-01 | DATE <= 2011-03-01)
```

Unfortunately, this just returns the original data, without doing any filtering.

Can anyone help?

Comment: try quoting the dates; right now you're doing 2006 - 4 - 1 == 2001.  You may need to do something like `DATE >= as.POSIXct("2006-04-01")`

Comment: @BrodieG, It won't work with `POSIXct` class for some reason, maybe it should be another research topic for you :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think I got my comment edit in about 2 seconds before your comment ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `DATE` contains only dates (without hours and etc, like in your example data above) you can convert it into `as.Date` class and then operate on it

```
model.weather$DATE <- as.Date(model.weather$DATE)

model.weather <- subset(model.weather, DATE >= "2006-04-01" & DATE <= "2011-03-01")
```

or (a better solution)

```
model.weather <- model.weather[model.weather$DATE >= "2006-04-01" & model.weather$DATE <= "2011-03-01", ]
```

Comment: Thanks, David.  Converting to as.Date helped, and your second (better) solution got me the rest of the way there!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `dplyr`, you can try something like this.

```
model.weather2 <- model.weather %>%
    filter(as.Date(DATE) <= "2006-04-01" & as.Date(DATE) >= "2011-03-01")
```

or

```
model.weather2 <- model.weather %>%
    filter(between(as.Date(DATE), as.Date("2006-04-01"), as.Date("2011-03-01")))
```